# Set Windows XP Lock Screen Background

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, lock-screen

I've googled this a bit, but have yet to find anything.

I have 4 monitors. when I lock my screen via <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, it turns 3 of them to the background color selected in background options, and the 4th one is the windowsXP login screen. I want to know if it's possible to make a background picture appear instead (right now the picture is actually my default background, I just want it to carry over when I lock my machine.

Comment: mifht depend on whether you use "welcome page/family logon" or the "classic" logon...

Comment: I'd agree with mihi, I use the classic logon, so it's just a small floating window, not an entire screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the TweakUI PowerToy had this as an option. Which means it's somewhere in the registry or local policy settings if you really want to dig there. TweakUI is quicker though.

Comment: And more precisely, where in TweakUI ? Because I just checked, and I can't find such option. The only thing is to copy the background to the logon screen.

Answer (score 1):

There is this kb article: [Changing Background Bitmap for the Windows NT Logon Screen](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103327)

I also just found [LogonStudio](http://www.stardock.com/products/logonstudio/) from an [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevecla01/archive/2007/11/19/change-your-vista-logon-screen.aspx). It seems to work well for Vista, haven't tired XP though.

Comment: It works good for XP too, but i'm not sure it answers the question, has this changes the logon screen only, not the "lock" one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself as I had one image on my desktop normally, but a totally different one (bliss) when the computer was locked.  If you want the same image for the lock screen (not the initial login), as you have for unlocked and working, make sure your image is a bitmap.  the image as a jpeg will be seen as web content and hidden when locked.

Comment: I use jpgs exclusively for backgrounds and they always show up when in Win-L on my 2-monitor setup, but I don't have any web content normally displayed on my desktop.  I have that feature turned off.

Comment: jpegs are considered web content from what i could find out.  when I used one as my background, it always reverted to bliss on lock, now it doesn't.